# Why flask doesn't work with gunicorn and telegram bot api?

Tags: flask, telegram, gunicorn, telegram-bot

I am using telegram bot api (telebot), flask and gunicorn.
When I use command `python app.py` everything is work fine but when I use python `wsgi.py` flask is stated on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and bot doesn't answer and if I am using `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8443 wsgi:app` webhook is setting but telegram bot doesn't answer. I tried to add app.run from app.py to wsgi.py but it doesn't work

app.py

```
import logging
import time
import flask
import telebot

API_TOKEN = '111111111:token_telegram'

WEBHOOK_HOST = 'droplet ip'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 8443  # 443, 80, 88 or 8443 (port need to be 'open')
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'  # In some VPS you may need to put here the IP addr

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = 'webhook_cert.pem'  # Path to the ssl certificate
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = 'webhook_pkey.pem'  # Path to the ssl private key

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (API_TOKEN)

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


# Empty webserver index, return nothing, just http 200
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD'])
def index():
    return ''


# Process webhook calls
@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)


# Handle all other messages
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


# Remove webhook, it fails sometimes the set if there is a previous webhook
bot.remove_webhook()
#
time.sleep(1)

# Set webhook
bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,
                certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Start flask server
    app.run(host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
            port=WEBHOOK_PORT,
            ssl_context=(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV),
            debug=True)
```

wsgi.py

```
from app import app  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice to show python webservers to the world. It's not secure.
Good practice - using a reverse proxy, e.g. `nginx`

#### Chain

So the chain shoud be:

`api.telegram.org -> your_domain -> your_nginx -> your_webserver -> your_app`

#### SSL

Your ssl certificates shoud be checked on `nginx` level. On success just pass request to your webserver (flask or something else). It's also a tip about `how to use infitity amount of bots on one host/port`  :)

How to configure nginx reverse proxy - you can find in startoverflow or google.

#### Telegram Webhooks

`telebot` is so complicated for using webhooks.
Try to use `aiogram` example. It's pretty simple:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.types import Message

WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://your.domain'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/path/to/api'

bot = Bot('BOT:TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: Message):
    return message.answer(message.text)


async def on_startup(dp: Dispatcher):
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_webhook(dispatcher=dp, on_startup=on_startup,
                           webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH, host='localhost', port=3000)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
app.run(host=0.0.0.0, port=5000, debug=True)
```

Change port number and debug arguments based on your case.

Comment: Webhook can be set up only on ports 80, 88, 443 or 8443

Comment: Try without port and debug argument. I had issues in the past without host=0.0.0.0

Comment: Never use 0.0.0.0! It's not secure! Only localhost + reverse proxy.